Why does importing a custom abc.py file not work as expected in Python?
I was reading the official documentation on modules. It says that when a module is imported, Python first searches for a built-in module with that name. If it is not found, it then searches in a list of directories given by the sys.path variable. The directories in my system are listed below:
['/home/user/Desktop/Python', '/usr/lib64/python313.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.13', '/usr/lib64/python3.13/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.13/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.13/site-packages']

I want to know whether abc module in Python a built-in module. To check this, I used the following code snippet:
import sys
print(sys.builtin_module_names)

I ran the above code and got the following output:
('_abc', '_ast', '_codecs', '_collections', '_functools', '_imp', '_io', '_locale', '_operator', '_signal', '_sre', '_stat', '_string', '_suggestions', '_symtable', '_sysconfig', '_thread', '_tokenize', '_tracemalloc', '_typing', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'atexit', 'builtins', 'errno', 'faulthandler', 'gc', 'itertools', 'marshal', 'posix', 'pwd', 'sys', 'time')

From the above output, it is clear that abc isn't a built-in module. Now, I want to test this in a different way. I created two files named main.py and abc.py in my Python directory (but the standard abc module is present in /usr/lib64/python3.13 directory). The code in these files is provided below:
# abc.py
var = 5

# main.py
import abc
print(abc.var)

Since abc isn't a built-in module, when I import it, my interpreter should search for it in my current directory. And since it is present in my current directory, I expected it to print 5. However, I got the following output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Python/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(abc.var)
          ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'var'

I have absolutely no clue why this is giving an error.

What does print(os.listdir(sys.path[0])) show? Done right before the import abc.

Also, what happens if you try the same thing with abcfoobar instead of abc?

@KellyBundy print(os.listdir(sys.path[0])) is giving ['main.py', 'abc.py']. Everything is working fine if I change the file name. In fact, it is also working as expected even with other standard module names.

In general, if you mess with stuff needed for the interpreter to work in the first place, weird stuff might happen, and abc falls under "needed for the interpreter to work".
abc is a pretty "core" stdlib module. It's imported by the io module, which is needed to initialize the built-in open function. init_set_builtins_open does the C equivalent of import builtins; from io import open; builtins.open = open:
    if (!(bimod = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins"))) {
        goto error;
    }

    if (!(wrapper = _PyImport_GetModuleAttrString("io", "open"))) {
        goto error;
    }

    /* Set builtins.open */
    if (PyObject_SetAttrString(bimod, "open", wrapper) == -1) {
        Py_DECREF(wrapper);
        goto error;
    }

And when it does that, since io imports abc, this causes the abc module to be loaded.
This happens pretty early in startup. It's so early, the script directory hasn't yet been prepended to sys.path. Python hasn't even decided what file or command it's going to run yet, and it can't set that sys.path entry until it's decided that. So the directory where your custom abc.py lives isn't on sys.path yet.
If your abc.py had been found? Well, like I said, io needs the standard abc module. So if your abc.py had been found instead, interpreter startup would probably fail entirely.

Incidentally, abc is also imported by a bunch of other stdlib modules, even including parts of importlib, which is where most of the import implementation lives. You might think initializing importlib is what'd trigger the abc import, but the parts of importlib that need abc aren't actually needed at interpreter startup. To figure out what specifically causes abc to be loaded, I ran Python with the -v flag to turn on import logging, to see what else is getting imported around the time abc gets imported.

abc is a Python standard library module, and not a built-in module. It is implemented as a regular .py file located in your Python installation's Lib directory, usually at Lib/abc.py.
The sys.builtin_module_names only lists C-implemented modules that are statically linked into the Python interpreter. Since abc is a Python file in the standard library, it doesn't appear there. However, _abc does because it is a built-in C module.
In order to see all available modules, you can simply run:
help('modules')

inside Python's console.


Exactly, 'abc' is a standard module. However, when I try to name a module as 'abc.py', it doesn't import properly. Instead of importing the module from the current directory, Python imports the standard abc module. That shouldn't be the case, right?

@Infinite I think it should prioritize modules from your directory before the built-ins and standard modules. But I think it also depends on the file structure of your project. Try an explicit import from . import abc and see how this is handled.

@Infinite "depends on your file structure of your project", meaning that if abc.py is not properly structured, it won't be found and thus, the standard module will be imported

Even with from abc import *, it still gives an error, and abc.py is in the same directory as main.py.
